# Preview links with SXA

Tags: sxa, link-manager

Let have example structure:

[image]

Normally when there is no `SXA tenants` exist and `New Sample Item` is published, `LinkBuilder.GetItemUrl()` will return something like

`https://sc93sc.dev.local/en/New-tenant/New-site/Home/New-Sample-Item`.

The problem is when SXA tenants are there. Then link should be created referring to it.

In short, I'm getting URL something like above which returns 404 when I try to use it. To make it work link has to be
`https://sc93sc.dev.local/en/New-Sample-Item`, so relative to tenant root, not Sitecore root.

Is there a way to get that without custom LinkProvider?

**Code:**

```
var siteName = "website";
var site = SiteContext.GetSite(siteName);
var options = new UrlOptions
            {
                AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true,
                Site = GetSiteForPreviewLink(),
                Language = Language.Parse(language.Name)
            };

var builder = new LinkProvider.LinkBuilder(options);
link = builder.GetItemUrl(sitecoreItem);
```

Comment: Are you using `LinkProvider` for Item URL? if yes, did you try by using `LinkManager.GetItemUrl` instead of it?

Comment: yes, and it giving the wrong result too "/sitecore/content/New-tenant/New-site/Home/New-Sample-Item".

Comment: Is `sc93sc.dev.local` added as a valid URL to the Site Grouping of `New Site`?

Comment: yes. It is an example of my local instance. Seems is is added by setting "AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true"

Comment: What is the GetSiteForPreviewLink doing in your code?

Comment: it was a helper method providing Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext object. Logic is just inlined in code in line 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Mistery solved. Kinda. To make sitecore root relative URLs work I needed to change value of Virtual Folder field in Settings of my "New site" from default "/" to some "/whatever". ‍♂️